# Maximum volume of cylinder obtained by rotating a rectangle

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

> Question: A cylinder is obtained by revolving a rectangle about the $x$-axis, the base of the rectangle lying on the $x$- axis and the entire rectangle lying in the region between the curve: $y=\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}$ and the $x$-axis. Find the maximum possible value of the cylinder so formed.

---

So I proceeded by first graphing out the function to get a visual:

[image: Function in question with the rectangle.]
Now, we call the length of the side of the rectangle parallel to the $y$ axis as $y$, and the length parallel to the $x$ axis as $x$. The volume of the cylinder formed with these parameters would be
$$V= πy^2x$$
If I find a relation between $x$ and $y$, I can differentiate the expression for volume, and arrive at the maximum value. This is where I'm exactly stuck. I can't find such a relation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider the line $y=c$ and we impose the condition

$c=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$

$cx^2-x+c=0$

that permit us to find two solutions $x_1,x_2$ in the definition domain of the intersection between the line and the curve, that corresponds in this case to $1-4c^2>0$

Moreover we obtain

$x_2-x_1=\frac{\sqrt{1-4c^2}}{c}$

But now

$V(c)=\pi c^2(x_2-x_1)=\pi c \sqrt{1-4c^2}$

What is the maximum value of $V(c)$?
The maximum point $c$ for $V(c)$ is exactly also the maximum point for $T=V^2(c)$, that is  simple to study:

$T(c)=V^2(c)=\pi^2 c^2(1-4c^2)$

and so

$T’(c)=2\pi^2 c(1-4c^2)-8\pi^2c^3\geq 0$

if and only if

$8c^3\leq c$ so $c^2\leq \frac{1}{8}$

Thus the maximum point for $V$ will be

$c=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$ and $V(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4})=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Great answer! Using difference of roots was what I wasn't thinking about